# Changing background image periodically ImageView

Tags: android, multithreading, performance, android-layout, imageview

I have layout FrameLayout as a root layout.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
 >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/background_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/init_image"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop">
    </ImageView>

......
......
</FrameLayout>
```

I need to change periodically some amount of images in a infinity loop (some condition) so like slideshow.
I have tried to use Handler but when I change I get OutOfMemory error.
I also tried ImageSwitcher but It seems not to work correctly.
Please give an example or advice how to implement it correctly following all design patterns of Android, thx.

Comment: You could use timers, to change the drawable of the imageview after a certain amount of desired time has passed

Comment: Use view pager which will slide images at described time interval

Comment: Try loading the new Image using AsyncTask and play some animations while changing the image after it gets loaded. Excute the asynctask in Handler with the time interval.

Answer (score 0):

Hye there , i was recently searching for this issue and came across a good solution as it doesn't apply automatic density based scaling of the images and use them as they are.

1- Put all your images in res/drawable-nodpi folder, you have to create this folder as it doesn't exist.

2 - Make them automatically change from one to other in an infinite loop.

```
int images[] = { R.drawable.background_1, 
        R.drawable.background_2,
        R.drawable.background_3, 
        R.drawable.background_4,
        R.drawable.background_5, 
        R.drawable.background_6,
        R.drawable.background_7 }; // i've these images in **res/drawable-nodpi**
```

Here is the onCreate method

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView_Animated); 

    handler.postDelayed(changeImage, 5000); // after every 5secs it will change image.

 }
```

Now here comes the part which handles all changing of images , outside onCreate do this.

```
    Runnable changeImage = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        if (count >6) {
            handler.removeCallbacks(changeImage);
        } else {

            if (count >= 6)
                count = 0;
            AlphaAnimation animation1 = new AlphaAnimation(0.5f, 1.0f); //here is a bit of animation for ya ;)
            animation1.setDuration(5000);
            animation1.setStartOffset(1300); //time for that color effect
            animation1.setFillAfter(true);
            imageView.startAnimation(animation1);
            imageView.setBackgroundResource(images[count++]);
            handler.postDelayed(changeImage, 5000);
            }
    }
};
```

All done, hope i helped you.